# When two plane mirror are inclined at 60° to each other?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection

How many images will be formed? In the case above I think 5 images will be form. But how can I exactly find out the number of images if the inclination angle is different. Is there any formula or it is just we have to draw a ray diagram for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a formula for this 
$$N=\frac{360}{A}-1$$
where $N$ is no: of images formed and $A$ is the angle

Hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Plane mirrors are inclined to each so as to produce many or multiple images.Theatre Art makes use of this on stage.[formular for finding the number of images formed when plane mirrors are incline is given as_N0=360-1/the angle¤]

Answer (score 0):

[image: The mirror image diagram]

i hope this diagram will make it more clear along with the above given formula.